# Hosting A Json File For Http Get Request

Tags: json, angular

I have a json file that I want to consume in my angular app via an http get request

My plan is to host the static json file in my amazon s3 bucket with public access.  The problem is trying to consume it in my angular app.

```
  getRanges() {

    return this.http.get("http://publicurl.json")
    .map(res => res.json(),
  (error) => this.sharedAppFunctions.showToast(error)
  );
  }
```

This is failing probably because it not a json response type.

Comment: using `HttpClient` or `Http`?

Comment: Http,   public http: Http,

Comment: and how does the response look like which you are getting? And you are getting an error message? If so, post that as well.

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution

```
getRanges() {
  return this.http.get("https://xxx/Ranging.json")
   .map(this.extractData);
}

private extractData(res: Response) {
  let body = res.json();
  return body.data || {};
}
```